# Why is it sufficient when proving dirac function identities to show that the action inside an integral is the same on both sides?

Tags: real-analysis, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

I am just starting with the Dirac function $\delta(x)$ (for physics) and proving some identities such as
$$ \delta(g(x))= \Sigma \frac{\delta(x-x_n)}{|g'(x_n)|}$$.

I am told that it is sufficient to prove

$$\int _{-\infty} ^{+\infty} \delta(g(x)) f(x) dx = \int _{-\infty} ^{+\infty}\Sigma \frac{\delta(x-x_n)}{|g'(x_n)|}  f(x) dx $$ for all functions $f(x)$. I suppose it has something to do with that $f(x)$ is arbitrary but I'm not quite seeing how the bottom one implies the top one.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the definition of what it means for two distributions to be equal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) ), at least once you specify exactly what functions $f(x)$ you consider. The Dirac delta function is not actually a function in the mathematical sense but it is a distribution.